# Step size is effectively zero

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I've been trying to solve Bodewadt flow equations which is a system of differential equations.

$$\begin{align*}
F^2 - G^2 + HF' - F'' + 1 &= 0 \\
2GF + HG'-G'' &= 0 \\
2F + H' &= 0
\end{align*}$$

with boundary conditions:

$$\begin{align*}
F(0)=G(0)=H(0)=0\\
F(\infty)=0,\;G(\infty)=1
\end{align*}$$

I turned them into a system of first order ordinary differential equations where $F=x;F'=y;G=z,G'=s$ and $H=p$. Thing is, I don't have the derivatives $F'(0)$ and $G'(0)$, so to make use of the infinite boundary conditions instead, I use a sufficiently large number instead of $\infty$. Approximately, $14$ works fine.

```
sol = {x[t], y[t], z[t], s[t], p[t]} /.
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t]^2 - z[t]^2 + s[t] y[t] + 1, 
s'[t] == 2 z[t] x[t] + p[t] s[t], z'[t] == s[t], p'[t] == -2 x[t],
 x[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, x[14] == 0, z[14] == 1}, {x, y, 
z, s, p}, {t, 0, 14}]
```

The problem is that when I run the code I have the next problem:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 3.4508216573870163`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I really am not acquainted with Mathematica, so I really don't how to solve a system of ODEs with boundary conditions at infinity.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a tag [tag:boundary-conditions-at-infinity] for questions related to your problem.  It’s almost certainly the `”StartingInitialConditions”` that are chosen for the `”ShootingMethod”` used for BVPs, which you can also look up in the docs.  Finally `Method -> “FiniteElement”` might work for you.

Comment: Hi, I really do not understand what you mean, I am not a native speaker, I guess BVPs stands for boundary value problems, is it a book? I don't know what you mean by docs, I am not acquainted with this page neither. Thanks!

Comment: "Docs" is short for "Documentation" or "Help" pages, like this one: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html, which discusses Boundary Value Problems (BVP).  You can also get to it through the menu Help > Wolfram Documentation in the desktop version (search for "BVP"). -- If click on the tag in my first comment, you will get a list of posts on this site dealing with boundary conditions at infinity.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Yet, when i click on the tag boundary-conditions-at-infinity of you first comment it says there no questioned tagged. Anyway, the documentation seems to be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was on a phone and mistyped. Try [tag:boundary-condition-at-infinity]

Comment: Thanks! I've now found a couple of similar questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that ODE systems with $\| X'\| \sim O(\| X \|^2)$ tend to be unstable, that is, a small rounding error has a chance to cause a solution to blow up. First, boundary-value problems (BVPs) are not guaranteed to have solutions, and without a proof or evidence that a solution exists, difficulty in solving one should raise the question whether there is a solution to find. Second, instability makes a BVP at infinity hard to solve numerically, even when solutions do exist.

I haven't made a thorough analysis of the problem, but I got lucky (I think it was luck).  When you get a `NDSolve::ndsz` error and no solution returned when solving a BVP, it is usually because of bad starting initial conditions that yield a singularity, which conditions are automatically chosen for the shooting method. The shooting method computes the solution to an initial-value problem (IVP) and adjusts the initial conditions (ICs) trying to get the solution to converge to the boundary conditions (BCs).

You can control the `"Shooting"` method of `NDSolve` somewhat (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html).  You can specify `"StartingInitialConditions"`, but sometimes this isn't enough. In such cases one might use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to manually implement a shooting method
([How to avoid NDSolve::ndsz problem (singularity problem)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72725/how-to-avoid-ndsolvendsz-problem-singularity-problem), [Nonlinear differential equation: numerical solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/nonlinear-differential-equation-numerical-solution/)).

In this case I tried `"StartingInitialConditions"`. The first guess gave `NDSolve::nderr` error test failure. If you know your ODE system, you might have insight into what are good guesses and what are not. I didn't have such insight, but I got lucky.  To give me a better chance, I reduce the precision and accuracy goals and raised the `WorkingPrecision`.  The goal was to get a pretty good solution and then to refine it.

```
odes = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t]^2 - z[t]^2 + s[t] y[t] + 1, 
  s'[t] == 2 z[t] x[t] + p[t] s[t], z'[t] == s[t], p'[t] == -2 x[t]};
bcs = {x[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, x[14] == 0, z[14] == 1};
vars = {x, y, z, s, p};
sol32 =
  NDSolve[{odes, bcs}, vars, {t, 0, 14}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {s[14] == 0, y[14] == 0, 
       p[14] == 0, x[14] == 0, z[14] == 1}}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

solMP =
 NDSolve[{odes, bcs}, vars, {t, 0, 14}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {
      Through[vars[14]] == Through[vars[14] /. First[sol32]]}
    },
  PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10
  ]

ListLinePlot[vars /. First[solMP], PlotLegends -> vars]
```

[image]

Check the BCs:

```
bcs /. Equal -> Subtract /. First[sol32] // Norm
bcs /. Equal -> Subtract /. First[solMP] // Norm
(*
  0.0337144277985927458402168128813
  5.99878*10^-6
*)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. It is, indeed, the solution I had been seeking.

Comment: @SebastiánFrades You’re welcome!

Comment: Luckily, the built-in shooting method worked right out of the box. If it gets bad enough, one would usually have to use `ParametricNDSolve(Value)` to manually implement shooting.

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment Yep, it's mentioned in the last sentence of the third paragraph.